# Faster way to multiplication in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame (name t) like this

```
ID N com_a com_b com_c
A  3   1     0    0
A  5   0     1    0
B  1   1     0    0
B  1   0     1    0
B  4   0     0    1
B  4   1     0    0
```

I have try to do `com_a*N com_b*N com_c*N`

```
ID N com_a com_b com_c com_a_N com_b_N com_c_N
A  3   1     0    0       3       0       0
A  5   0     1    0       0       5       0
B  1   1     0    0       1       0       0
B  1   0     1    0       0       1       0
B  4   0     0    1       0       0       4     
B  4   1     0    0       4       0       0
```

I use `for`-function, but it need many time how do i do the fast in the big data

```
for (i in 1:dim(t)[1]){
    t$com_a_N[i]=t$com_a[i]*t$N[i]
    t$com_b_N[i]=t$com_b[i]*t$N[i]
    t$com_c_N[i]=t$com_c[i]*t$N[i]
    }
```

Comment: how big is your data set?

Comment: `t` is not a good name for a data set in R, as it's a stored function

Comment: @BenBolker the data is 1085350*70.

Comment: are you doing the multiplication for columns 2:69?

Comment: @BenBolker have to multiplication for columns 4:70. the variable N is in the 3 columns

Comment: so you need to expand the data frame out to 3*(1+66) columns?

Comment: @BenBolker i need to output 3*(4 to 70) columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t <- transform(t,
      com_a_N=com_a*N,
      com_b_N=com_b*N,
      com_c_N=com_c*N)
```

should be *much* faster.  `data.table` solutions might be faster still.

Comment: I think `transform(t, com_a_N=ifelse(com_a, com_a, N))` could work too

Comment: yes.  I didn't look carefully enough at the structure of the data to see that the `com` columns were all binary ...

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sweep` for this

```
(st <- sweep(t[, 3:5], 1, t$N, "*"))
#  com_a com_b com_c
#1     3     0     0
#2     0     5     0
#3     1     0     0
#4     0     1     0
#5     0     0     4
#6     4     0     0
```

The new names can be created with `paste` and `setNames`, and you can add the new columns to the existing data.frame with `cbind`.  This will scale for any number of columns.

```
cbind(t, setNames(st, paste(names(st), "N", sep="_")))
#  ID N com_a com_b com_c com_a_N com_b_N com_c_N
#1  A 3     1     0     0       3       0       0
#2  A 5     0     1     0       0       5       0
#3  B 1     1     0     0       1       0       0
#4  B 1     0     1     0       0       1       0
#5  B 4     0     0     1       0       0       4
#6  B 4     1     0     0       4       0       0
```

Answer (score 3):

A `data.table` solution as proposed by @BenBolker

```
library(data.table)
setDT(t)[, c("com_a_N", "com_b_N", "com_c_N") := list(com_a*N, com_b*N, com_c*N)]

##    ID N com_a com_b com_c com_a_N com_b_N com_c_N
## 1:  A 3     1     0     0       3       0       0
## 2:  A 5     0     1     0       0       5       0
## 3:  B 1     1     0     0       1       0       0
## 4:  B 1     0     1     0       0       1       0
## 5:  B 4     0     0     1       0       0       4
## 6:  B 4     1     0     0       4       0       0
```

Comment: You can also use `.SD` along with `lapply` with `.SDcols`.. Maybe you could add that as well?

Comment: @Arun, not sure how to that effectively, maybe you'd add this a separate answer or your edit? `setDT(t)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x*N, N), .SDcols = c("com_a", "com_b", "com_c")]` didn't work

Comment: The LHS is the same (although you can use `paste` to generate them rather than typing it out), then `:=`, then RHS would have `lapply(.SD, ...)` instead of creating the list manually, then `.SDcols`. Want to try again? ;)

Comment: @Arun, The only way I could make it to work is `setDT(t)[, c("com_a_N", "com_b_N", "com_c_N") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x*N), .SDcols = c("com_a", "com_b", "com_c", "N")]` but this is essentially parsing 4 variables into 3. How can I make `lapply` recognize `N` without parsing it into `.SDcols`?

Comment: Hm, yes dint think of that. You're right. Perhaps better to leave it then until [this one](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5222&group_id=240&atid=975) is fixed..

Answer (score 2):

Even faster using matrix multiplication:

```
cbind(dat,dat[,3:5]*dat$N)
```

Though you should set colnames after....

To avoid using explicit column index(not recommended) , you can use some `grep`  magic:

```
cbind(dat,dat[,grep('com',colnames(dat))]*dat$N)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `dplyr`:

```
require(dplyr)

t <- mutate(t, com_a_N=com_a*N,
               com_b_N=com_b*N,
               com_c_N=com_c*N)
```

Comment: I don't see any benefit to this over the `transform()` solution -- is `mutate` faster or otherwise different in a way that matters here ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker I haven't compared the performances. Just thought it might be another option to try since, as far as I understood, dplyr is in some cases faster than base R (I don't know if this applies in this case).

Comment: I don't actually think it'll make very much difference here (I think the big advantage of `dplyr` is over `plyr`, which is elegant but slow, not necessarily over base R).

Comment: @BenBolker in that case my apologies for posting an answer that is not significantly different from one of the previous answers (yours in this case). Lack of knowledge on my side.

Comment: actually, comment in R chat room suggests you may be right and I may be wrong: "the only issue is if the entire object is being copied to add the new columns. And mutate from dplyr shallow copies (and so does R 3.1.0), whereas transform in R versions prior to 3.1.0 would copy the entire object. So, if you've a large object( > 2GB) + R < 3.1.0, then you're more likely see a difference."

Comment: Could also be formulated in dplyr like this: `t %>% group_by(ID, N) %>% mutate_each(funs(. * N))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, but why `group_by`?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck wouldnt this mutate/overwrite the existing columns? I think the OP wanted to add new columns

Comment: In that case `t %>% mutate_each(funs(. * N), vars = starts_with("com"))`