# How do I reference a column in lapply which is not part of the SD?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column in my `data.table` which contains the data I'd like to use to update a bunch of other columns. This data is a list, and I need to subset the list based on the value in each of the columns that I'll include in my SD expression

#### My data....

```
dt <- data.table( A = list( c("X","Y") , c("J","K") ) , B = c(1,2) , C = c(2,1) )
#     A B C
#1: X,Y 1 2
#2: J,K 2 1
```

#### My desired result....

```
#     A B C
#1: X,Y X Y
#2: J,K K J
```

#### What I tried....

```
# Column A is not included in SD so not found...
dt[ , lapply( .SD , function(x) A[x] ) , .SDcols = 2:3 ]
#Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : object 'A' not found


# This also does not work. See's all of A as one long vector (look at results for C)
for( i in 2:3 ) dt[ , names(dt)[i] := unlist(A)[ get(names(dt)[i]) ] ]
#     A B C
#1: X,Y X Y
#2: J,K Y X

# I saw this in another answer, but also won't work:
# Basically we add an ID column and use 'by=' to try and solve the problem  above
# Now we get a type mismatch
dt <- data.table( ID = 1:2 , A = list( c("X","Y") , c("J","K") ) , B = c(1,2) , C = c(2,1) , key = "ID" )
for( i in 3:4 ) dt[ , names(dt)[i] := unlist(A)[ get(names(dt)[i]) ] , by = ID ]
#Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(names(dt)[i], unlist(A)[get(names(dt)[i])]),  : 
#  Type of RHS ('character') must match LHS ('double'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)
```

If anyone is interested my real data is a set of SNPs and INDELS across different isolates and I am trying to do this:

```
# My real data looks more like this:
# In columns V10:V15;
# if '.' in first character then use data from 'Ref' column
# else use integer at first character to subset list in 'Alt' column
#   Contig  Pos V3 Ref Alt    Qual        V10       V11       V12       V13       V14       V15
#1:     1   172  .   T   C 81.0000  1/1:.:.:. ./.:.:.:. ./.:.:.:. ./.:.:.:. ./.:.:.:. ./.:.:.:.
#2:     1   399  .   G C,A 51.0000  ./.:.:.:. 1/1:.:.:. 2/2:.:.:. ./.:.:.:. 1/1:.:.:. ./.:.:.:.
#3:     1   516  .   T   G 57.0000  ./.:.:.:. 1/1:.:.:. ./.:.:.:. 1/1:.:.:. ./.:.:.:. ./.:.:.:.
```

Comment: hmm, didn't read the whole thing but maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848224/faster-way-to-multiplication-in-data-frame/23850411#comment36705889_23850411)  comment will be helpfull?

Comment: Is the number in your `B` and `C` column representative of which element of `A` belongs in that column?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor yes it is cheers.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I can't seem to view the FR that your comment links to.

Comment: is `A` always just two elements?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon, trackers are closed for public on R-Forge. `data.table` has moved to [github](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) (Matt informed on the  mailing list). [Here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/495) is the issue David referenced to.

Comment: I don't think your attempt would have worked even in the absence of the `.SDcols` issue, since it's equivalent to: `dt[ , lapply( .SD[, -1, with = F], function(x) A[x])]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapply` and `set` with a for loop. There may be more efficient ways

```
for(j in c('B','C')){
    set(dt, j = j, value = mapply(FUN = '[', dt[['A']],dt[[j]]))
}
 dt
#      A B C
# 1: X,Y X Y
# 2: J,K K J
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi does this work for you ?

```
dt$B <- apply(dt, 1, FUN = function(x) x$A[x$B])
dt$C <- apply(dt, 1, FUN = function(x) x$A[x$C])
dt
#     A B C
#1: X,Y X Y
#2: J,K K J
```

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, thanks, but I am trying to use a `data.table` solution because I have some quite big tables to work on (many individuals, hundreds of thousands of SNPs).

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant way to do this and it doesn't scale well but here goes...

```
dt[,A1:=lapply(A,'[[',1)]
dt[,A2:=lapply(A,'[[',2)]
dt[B==1,`:=`(Bnew=A1,Cnew=A2)]
dt[B==2,`:=`(Bnew=A2,Cnew=A1)]
dt[,`:=`(A1=NULL,A2=NULL,B=NULL,C=NULL)]
setnames(dt,c("Bnew","Cnew"),c("B","C"))
```